# PHP: extract some part of a string variable

Tags: php, explode

i have a variable look like this:

```
$var1 = "33081PA-5112";
```

some time it become:

```
$var1 = "33083";
$var1 = "33081PA-1132";
$var1 = "31183";
$var1 = "13081PA-2132";
```

how do i determine when it has the PA-, so when it does i want to get the number value after the PA- into other variable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<?php
    $var1 = "13081PA-2132";
    $pos = strpos( $var1, 'PA-');
    echo $pos . "\n";

    if( $pos > -1 )
    {
        $newVal = substr($var1, $pos+3 );

        echo $newVal;
    }
?>
```

Output:

```
5
2132
```

Answer (score 1):

Use strpos():

```
if(strpos($var,'PA-') !== false) // code to run if the string has a PA-
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you what you want.

```
$var1 = "33081PA-1132";
preg_match('/^([0-9]*)PA-/',$var1,$match);
$var1_cut = $match[1];
preg_match('/PA-([0-9]*)/',$var1,$match);
$var2 = $match[1];

//Outputs
print_r($var1);     //33081PA-1132
print_r($var1_cut); //33081
print_r($var2);     //1132
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `regex` match:

```
preg_match("{PA-(\d+)}",$var,$array);
echo $array[1][0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$var1 = "33083";
$var1 = "33081PA-1132";

if(strstr($var1, 'PA') !== false){ // If it has the PA
    $parts = explode('PA-', $var1); // Split by dash

    echo $parts[0]; // Left part
    echo '<br />';
    echo $parts[1]; // Right part
}else{
    echo $var1; // It has not PA
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(trim(str_replace(range(0,9),'', $var1)) == 'PA-') { 
  //do stuff
}
```